# Degrading OpenSSL version on xampp to recreate Heartbleed

Tags: apache, openssl, xampp, heartbleed-bug

I'm trying to recreate the heartbleed attack on a localhost apache server. I'm running xampp 1.8.3-2 on my ubuntu, and I want to degrade my OpenSSL version from 1.0.1e to 1.0.1b. I found out some info on the net on how to do this on windows, but nothing about linux - only how to update obviously. What are the files I need to replace, and where can I find the files for 1.0.1b?

Thanks In advance!

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: You should probably download a past version of XAMPP built against the vulnerable version of the OpenSSL library. XAMPP's download page has a ***More Downloads*** link. Follow it [Sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files/) and download what you want or need.